# How to set "keyboard tab borders" not to cover the rest of the UI?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm working on a UWP app and I'm having some trouble with the visual states of some UI controls, specifically with buttons and toggle buttons.

Basically, I'd like the borders that become visible when you press the TAB key (to navigate using the keyboard) to have the same ZIndex of the rest of the control, ie. if part of the control is covered, they should be covered too in the same way. But, it looks like these borders are always displayed on top of the UI, no matter what. Here's a screen:

[image]

You can see the border going over the rest of the UI, while the rest of that toggle button is correctly covered. The same happens for buttons as well (not only toggle buttons), see here:

[image]

I've looked at the template for these controls, but I couldn't find anything related to these specific borders, nor to anything like an explicit `Canvas.ZIndex` setting or something like that.

I guess this behavior is on purpose, but is there a way to change this and make those borders behave like the rest of the UI?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** here you can see how a reveal highlight effect is correctly covered by the shadow and the other UI elements on the right, but the TAB border ignores that and is displayed on top of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed similar behavior was previously present in the Start menu as well (although it wasn't with focus border, but with the reveal effect clearly "continuing" into the cut-off portion of the button.

One workaround that comes to mind is to observe the state of the `SplitView` and when it is closed to actually change the width of the buttons (for example via a `StateTrigger`). This way the button's area will no longer be "hidden" and the focus border will work properly, as the buttons will end where they should.